# Discord.js Bot Reaction Command with gif

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I want that if someone types in the command `.hello (ping user)`, that there is a gif in an embed which shows that expression. My problem now is that I dont know how to this with a different user than myself. So I can type `.hello` and then there is my Discord Username and the gif, but I dont know how that works with other users. I hope someone can help me.

Code:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    var user = message.mention.member;
    if (message.content == ".retarded" + user) {
        
         const retarded = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
           .setColor('#000033')
           .addFields(
              { name: user , value: "Text" },
           )
           .setImage(
               "https://media.tenor.com/images/782baae8b076ea2e1ffd7ab7f0df8010/tenor.gif"
           )
           .setTimestamp()
           .setFooter(message.author.username);

        message.channel.send(retarded)
        console.log(message.member.user.tag +' executed command .RETARDED')
    }
})


    
client.login(config.token)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the User or a GuildMember using [mentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions), you can try:

```
message.mentions.users.first() //User
```

or

```
message.mentions.members.first() //GuildMember
```

which will return the first entry in the collection. You can store them, and access the properties and methods of that object.

**Note:-** GuildMember and User are different from each other.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Whenever I type the command it shows the error "Cannot read property of first" in powershell

Comment: I suppose you didn't paste the full error. If the error is `Cannot read property 'first' of null` then its because you didn't mention the member. Meaning you need to ping the member.

Comment: The error is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined

Comment: You must have misspelled `.members` or `.users` (which ever you are using). Can you please check if its the exact same that I have given?

Comment: They weren't and the error is fixed now. Thanks for that. But unfortunately, the command still is not working...

Comment: Well what you are doing is wrong. You are getting the member mention, and then checking for message content. You don't need to check if `user` is present in the content. Because the condition will satisfy no matter if there's a mention or not. So just check`if(message.content==='.retarded')`. That should work.

Comment: Sorry if i am stupid but I still dont get what you mean. I will post my code in the comments here and it would be nice if you could fix it. But I understand if you dont want anymore
`client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content === ".retarded" + message.mentions.members.first()) {
         const retarded = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
           .setColor('#000033')
           .addFields(
              { name: message.mentions.members.first() , value: "text" }
           )
`

Comment: `
          .setImage(
               "https://media.tenor.com/images/782baae8b076ea2e1ffd7ab7f0df8010/tenor.gif"
           )
           .setTimestamp()
           .setFooter(message.author.username);

        message.channel.send(retarded)
        console.log(message.member.user.tag +' executed command .RETARDED')
    }
})
`

Comment: Just do `if(message.content.startsWith('.retarted')){ var mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();}` and then do the rest of the thing that you need to. If you want to use the member again, then you can use `mentionedMember` and access his properties. If you need more help, you can join the official discord.js discord server.